# Using Get-ChildItem with Get-Content

Tags: powershell, csv

I’m trying to make a list of file properties and the content of the first line in the files.

The command:

```
get-ChildItem -Recurse *.txt | select-object Name, DirectoryName, Length
```

gives me the names, the directory names and the lengh of the files in each directory.

I need also the content of the first line as well as the number of lines of each *.txt-file. In the end all the information should be in one CSV-file. How can I do that?

Example:

```
File_01.txt, C:\folder, 243, Text of the first line of the File_01.txt, number of lines in File_01.txt
File_02.txt, C:\folder, 290, Text of the first line of the File_02.txt, number of lines in File_02.txt
File_03.txt, C:\folder, 256, Text of the first line of the File_03.txt, number of lines in File_03.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [*calculated properties*](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730948.aspx) to add the `first line` and `number of lines` properties to the current object and pipe the result to the `Export-Csv` cmdlet:

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse *.txt | 
    select-object Name, 
        DirectoryName, 
        Length, 
        @{l='first line'; e={$_ |Get-Content -First 1}}, 
        @{l='number of lines'; e={$_ | Get-Content | Measure-Object | select -ExpandProperty Count}} |
    Export-Csv -Path 'C:\test.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Thank you! That worked perfect for me. 
I’m trying to filter the results for files with the string “Transaction Report” in them. 

The pipe: 

`| where-object {$_ | select-string –pattern “Transaction Report” -eq $true}`

Because a positional parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name “eq”. How can I filer those files according to a string pattern?

Comment: You are welcome Ron. Please consider to accept the answer. Also, please start a new question

Answer (score 0):

you can create an object too

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse *.txt | %{ 
    New-Object psobject -Property @{
    Name=$_.Name 
    DirectoryName=$_.DirectoryName
    Length=$_.Length
    FirstLine= Get-Content $_ -First 1
    Numberline=(gc $_).Count
    }

  } | Export-Csv -Path 'C:\test.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```